# Using matlab to read textfile but then skip lines with a # sign at the beginning of them

Tags: matlab, parsing, text-files

```
    function [input]= read_input()

    fid= fopen ('input.txt');

    tline=fgets(fid);

           while ischar(tline)
                if tline =='#'

                end
             tline = fgets(fid);
    end

        fclose(fid)
```

This is my code so far I'm trying to read a file and then just take the numerically values while skipping the lines that start with a #.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend a different approach.

Take advantage of the built-in functionality MATLAB provides, and use `textscan`:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n', 'CommentStyle', '#');
C = C{:};
fclose(fid);
```

After this, you'll end up with a cell array `C` that contains all the lines from your input file that don't start with a hash sign.

Comment: I'm getting error using textscan param/value pairs must come in pairs

Comment: @Jacob sorry, forgot the `fid` in the `textscan` call. Try it now.

Comment: Its still not pulling any kind of information off the text file

Comment: @Jacob It works for me, so you'll have to provide me with more details if you want me to help. What does your input file look like? What does your cell array `C` contain after running this?

Comment: Here is some of the text file, Im using notepad.                                   # number of external forces and moments
2 1
# coordinates of the points at which external forces are applied
# x y z
0.0 1.0 1.0
5.0 3.0 0.0
# magnitude and direction of external forces
# F dx dy dz
11.0 3.0 2.0 -9.0
0.1 3.0 1.0 1.0

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, Im not getting a cell array c

Comment: So I debugged it and I see a C array but then it goes away as I step through

Comment: Wait I got it, my output on my function wasnt c so I changed it

Comment: Yes thank you very much! Now taking that array can I divide it into separate matrices that can be used in other functions? Or should I make that a new question to ask?

Comment: @Jacob It's a different issue, so asking another question is preferred. you really need to. But it's probably best if you _search_ the internet for a possible solution first. Chances are that your question is already answered somewhere, even here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `if`

```
if tline(1) =='#'
    continue;
end
```

Comment: Ok, it just creates a busy in the lower left

Comment: Also, this doesn't ignore whitespace before the hash sign.